# If event date is less than now, show foo. If event date is greater than now, show bar

Tags: php, if-statement, timestamp

I have an events page on my website and I run a event bar at the top of my header showing the latest event. I'm trying to figure out how to write this correctly.

If the event has not happened I want to show it. If the event has already happened I do not want to show the event.

**CODE:**

```
<?php //SELECT QUERY...
    foreach($events->results() as $e):
$now = "now()";
    if($e->event_date <= $now){?>   
        <h1>Show Event</h1>

<?php } 
    elseif($e->event_date > $now){ ?>
        <h1>DON'T Show Event</h1>
<?php
}
    endforeach;
```

So basicly if the event's timestamp is less than or equal to the upcoming event, I want it to show.

If the event's timestamp is greater than the current date and time of the event, I do not want it to show.

Database table for events.
[image]

Comment: Timestamp is the standard datetime version or Unix Timestamp?

Comment: what is data type of event_date in db.

Comment: what value in event_date ?

Comment: See updated image of my table. I use the Post Date to capture when the event was posted and the event_date to change to the date and time of the event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`now()` is mysql function . In PHP we use **[time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)** to get  the current timestamp

It is used as

```
$now = time();// get current timestamp
```

Use [**`strtotime()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert date in time stamp then use for comparison

```
$now = time();
foreach ($events->results() as $e):
    if (strtotime($e->event_date) >= $now) {// check for greater then equal to
        ?>   
        <h1>Show Event</h1>
        <?php
    } else {
        echo "<h1>DON'T Show Event</h1>";
    }
endforeach;
```

Comment: Remove elseif, there is not requirement of it.

Comment: @Saty I've tried your way step by step. Not working for some reason. Also in this case I want it to read No event at this time, so the else if or just an else statement would be required. Not sure what the deal is. Your code looks solid..? Could it be the two timestamps in my database?

Comment: @echo Check updated answer for else statement for no event

Comment: @echo check my answer

Comment: @RakeshKumar I tried your method and Saty's method. Doesn't seem to be working..?

Comment: @echo use if condition as `if (strtotime($e->event_date) >= $now) {`

Comment: @Saty Using the greater or equal to worked, but I need it to be less than or equal to in my if statment

Comment: can you check this it is working for you as desired:-
  $evData = "2016-09-05 10:10:10";
  if ($evData <= date("Y-m-d H:i:s")){
    echo "foo";
  }else{
    echo "bar";
  }

 Test it by providing 2-3 sample dates $evData = "2016-09-05 10:10:10";

Comment: @Saty using the greater than or equal to Worked! I'm glad that it works but how does that make sense? Seems opposite to what I was trying to do..?

Comment: @Saty this was what worked.
`$now = time();
if (strtotime($e->event_date) >= $now)`

Comment: @echo man your statement contradicts with answer, in your statement you asked to show past events rather then future events. But final answer is results to show future events.

Answer (score 1):

You are in right Direction, change it like

```
<?php //SELECT QUERY...
    foreach($events->results() as $e):
       $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
       if(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($e->event_date)) >= $now){   
          echo "<h1>Show Event</h1>";
       }else{
          echo "<h1>DON'T Show Event</h1>";
       }
    endforeach;
  ?>
```

Comment: You also try your best!!